# How change the life time of existing particles in CCParticleSystemQuad?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, ccparticlesystem

I have a `CCParticleSystemQuad` and it generated many particles with `setLifeVaule(40)`.
Now, in the runtime, I want to change the life value of the existing particles `in fewer value` such as `0.1`.
But `setLife() function does not affect` existing particles.how can i change the life Time of them?